# I want to animate my list items( quotes in this case) using transition-group(vue js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vue-component, css-animations

I wanted to animate the quotes added by the user using transition-group but the code is misbehaving.

```
    <transition-group name="fade" tag="div" class="row">
        <Quote v-for="(quote, index) in quotes" :key="index + 1" @click.native="removeQuote(index)">
           {{ index + 1 }}. {{ quote }}
        </Quote> 
    </transition-group>
```

This is my code.
I want to have a fade-in animation upon adding a new item and fade-out upon removing one.
Thank You!

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at [the documentation about transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html). They are listing pretty straight-forward examples. If this doesn't help, please elaborate what you have tried and where exactly you're blocked or in which form your code is _misbehaving_.

Comment: once i add or delete a new item the fade animation is only applied on the last one and not on the one its supposed to be. Thank you for the reply though!

Comment: Please add the `removeQuotes(index)` function to your post.
I couldn't quite understand if you want the transition only on the element currently added/removed or on the whole group of `Quotes`?